# ESAPI Upgrade from 2.2.0.0 to 2.3.0.0 in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, esapi

I'm upgrading my spring boot project to 2.7.10 and in our project we are using maven artifact esapi - 2.2.0.0. As part of our upgrade we are also upgrading esapi artifact with the version mentioned below.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
<artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
<version>2.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm trying to upgrade esapi to 2.3.0.0 based on release notes recommendation https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/documentation/esapi4java-core-2.2.1.0-release-notes.txt#L128-L155

In my spring boot project class path I added ESAPI.properties and overriding with below properties. Because I'm using SL4J logging.

```
 ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory
 ESAPI.LogEncodingRequired=false
```

I still always getting the following error that is always referring to org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory. Not sure why it is not picking the one which I overridden in ESAPI.properites. Also I see ESAPI.properties in classpath. Any thoughts would be really helpful.`

```
Caused by: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory LogFactory class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory) must be in class path.
 at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:108) 
at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.logFactory(ESAPI.java:139)
at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.getLogger(ESAPI.java:155)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.<init>(DefaultEncoder.java:83)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.<init>(DefaultEncoder.java:106)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.getInstance(DefaultEncoder.java:67)
... 104 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.loadClassByStringName(ObjFactory.java:158)
at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:81)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 possible explanations here.

Most likely is that you have a second **ESAPI.properties** file that if being found and used prior to the one that updated and it still has the old value for **ESAPI.Logger**. If you do *not* have the system property "org.owasp.esapi.logSpecial.discard" set to true, when you first start your application that uses ESAPI, there will be some output sent to stdout. If you capture the stdout when you application server starts up, you should see output that looks something like:

```
...
ESAPI: WARNING: System property [org.owasp.esapi.opsteam] is not set
ESAPI: WARNING: System property [org.owasp.esapi.devteam] is not set
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
ESAPI: Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /home/wallk/work/esapi-work/kww-2.5.2.0-release/ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: /home/wallk/work/esapi-work/kww-2.5.2.0-release/target/test-classes/esapi/ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Loaded 'ESAPI.properties' properties file
...
```

Look through the output says your **ESAPI.properties** was loaded and the previous line should indicate where it was located at. Make sure LOCATION that is the place where you intended it to be found and corresponds to the version that you updated.

The overall class Javadoc for [DefaultSecurityConfiguration](https://javadoc.io/static/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.5.2.0/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.html) describes the search algorithm to locate **ESAPI.properties**.

The second possibility that could cause what you are observing (although I think it is much less likely than the first) is that the **ESAPI.properties** file you *are* loading has multiple values for **ESAPI.Logger** defined.

Comment: Kevin - Thanks for your inputs. I cross checked in my stdout / logs and I don't see any output that you mentioned. Also I tried adding org.owasp.esapi.logSpecial.discard=true in ESAPI.properties still same issue. Need to understand more on my side from where "org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory" reference is picking in my code. Currently I'm out of my options. Also I cross checked ESAPI.properties but I don't see multiple values for ESAPI.Logger.

Comment: This output would go to stdout (or maybe stderr, but I'm pretty sure it's stdout). And setting the property org.owasp.esapi.logSpecial.discard has to be a System property, so you can't put it in ESAPI properties. Try starting your application server with '-Dorg.owasp.esapi.logSpecial.discard=false' (not 'true') on the 'java' command line. A value of 'true' suppresses the output. If you can't get it to work, try running with a debugger and set a breakpoint in DefaultSecurityConfiguration.loadConfiguration() method.